# refactor this long but simple code - string comparing

Tags: java, string

Given two strings, return true if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive"). Note: str.toLowerCase() returns the lowercase version of a string.

endOther("Hiabc", "abc") → true

endOther("AbC", "HiaBc") → true

endOther("abc", "abXabc") → true

```
public class endOtherClass{  
      public static void main(String args[]) {  
          boolean is = endOther("yz","12xz") ;  
          System.out.println(is) ;  

      }  

     public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {  

       a = a.toLowerCase() ;  
       b = b.toLowerCase() ;  

       if( a.length() == b.length()){  
                System.out.println("a and b have same length!") ;  

                if(a.equals(b)){  
                     System.out.println("wow, even better - they are exact same") ;   
                     return true ;  
                          }  
                else {  
                          System.out.println("but are diff!") ;  
                           return false ;  
                          }  
       }  

            String shorter = "" ;// figure out which - a or b - is shorter   
            String longer = "" ;// and which one is longer  

            if( a.length() > b.length() ){ shorter = b ; longer = a ;}   
            else { shorter = a ; longer = b ;}  

            int offset = longer.length() - shorter.length() ; // the offset is used to know where exactly to start comparing  


            //go through the shorter and compare the corresponding part of the longer string  

            for(int i = 0 ; i < shorter.length() ; i++){  
                 System.out.println("comparing subs: " + shorter.substring(i,i+1) + " and " + longer.substring(offset+i, offset+i+1)) ;   


             if( !shorter.substring(i,i+1).equals( longer.substring(offset+i, offset+i+1) ) ){    //we add offset so we can start comparing the last n characters of shorter string!  

                   System.out.println("something wrong in long: " + longer.substring(offset+i, offset+i+1)) ;  

                   System.out.println("something wrong in short: " + shorter.substring(i,i+1)) ;  
                   return false ;  
                 }  
            }  
            return true ;  

      }  


    }
```

i m 90% sure this code can be simplified, but i don't know other logic or way of thinking about this simple exercise

can someone help me refactor it and make it smaller?

Comment: This may be more suitable for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to check for null cases.

```
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    if(a == null || b == null) {
      return false;
    }    
    String lowerA = a.toLowerCase();
    String lowerB = b.toLowerCase();
    return lowerA.endsWith(lowerB) || lowerB.endsWith(lowerA);
}
```

Comment: omg , the code is so short... thanks John Castle, this solution is the most elegant

Answer (score 5):

```
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {

    return a.toLowerCase().endsWith(b.toLowerCase()) || 
           b.toLowerCase().endsWith(a.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: I was just going to post the endsWith solution.

Comment: This must be the answer. Nice solution =D

Comment: What if a or b are null ? You get an exception from your code

Answer (score 1):

you can just use `"myString".toLowerCase().endsWith("ing")`
instead the loop you did

Comment: why vote down? is it jelousy?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply re-factor your code by using regex

1)  Regex approach

```
"abC".toLowerCase().matches("bc"+"$");
```

basically bc is the part of Regular expression so dollar sign indicates this target string must end with "bc". you can change this "bc" to suit your need. And "abC" is the target String.

2) String endWith approach

Tribute to Dima Goltsman

```
"myString".toLowerCase().endsWith("ing")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
   int minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
   a = a.substring(a.length - minLength).toLower();
   b = b.substring(b.length - minLength).toLower();
   return a.equals(b);
}
```

I'm not sure about Java syntax, but you can get idea from this code...